# Android IPC and service_manager

Tags: android, ipc, android-binder

Does all Android IPC is pass through the service_manager?
How does applications interacts with services and intents?

Does all messages passed through the service_manager as a proxy?
or applications can "talk" directly?

Comment: Hi, I like this question and I also have some further questions here.
Instead of creating a new question, I would like to add my questions here.

1. I think all service need to register to service manager and then the client can request the reference from it. Hence, I assume that the service can be found in adb shell service list when I start the service. Is this correct ? Only those shown in the list are capable of doing IPC thing.

Answer (score 0):

Once the connection is made, applications are talking directly (well, actually via the kernel).

Comment: @omri-c What do you mean by service_manager? There are mechanisms to exchange binder references between processes. Once you have one of these you can bind to the other process. You may want to look up the `Binder` and `IBinder` documentation.

Comment: There is service_manager.c and also ServiceManager.cpp, what is the difference between them? how are they connected ?

Comment: It actually finally goes to binder driver in the kernel layer and does the IPC through shared memory way.